# How to compare values of properties in test object via "where" using Ramda

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, ramda.js

Using the Ramdajs' "where" function (see: ["where" - ramda docs](http://ramdajs.com/0.19.1/docs/#where)) i'd like to create a test object which compares the values of the properties among themselves.

Example:

```
        let pred = R.where({
            a: predTestA(...),
            b: predTestB(...),
            c: predTestC(...)
        });
```

Therefore i'd like to write a Test Method that compares the values of a, b and c.

Example:

```
// Test if the value of "a" is higher or equal than all other values

let predTestA = (...) => {
  if ((valA >= ValB) || (valA >= ValC)) {
    return true
  } else {
    return false
  }
}
```

Questions:

1. How can i access the values of the properties?
2. Do you see a better way to accomplish the comparison of the object values?

Thanks for your help!

Muff

Comment: To better compare just: `return (valA >= ValB) || (valA >= ValC);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ramda does not offer that.  I believe it once did, but it was little used.  It would be easy enough to write your own version of `where` that does this, though:

```
const myWhere = curry(function (spec, testObj) {
  for (var prop in spec) {
    if (R.has(prop, spec) && !spec[prop](testObj[prop], testObj)) {
//                                                      ^^^^^^^
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
});
```

The highlighted bit is the only real difference from the Ramda version.

```
// Remember the triangle inequality from geometry class?
const triangular = myWhere({
  a: (a, t) => a < t.b + t.c,
  b: (b, t) => b < t.a + t.c,
  c: (c, t) => c < t.a + t.b
});

triangular({a: 3, b: 4, c: 9}); //=> false
triangular({a: 3, b: 6, c: 8}); //=> true
triangular({a: 7, b: 1, c: 5}); //=> false
triangular({a: 2, b: 8, c: 4}); //=> false
triangular({a: 3, b: 4, c: 5}); //=> true
```

If you think this is important enough and should go back into Ramda itself, feel free to [raise an issue](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues).

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot :)